Design rule error
I just made a PCB and updated the component form schematic to PCB:I even did not do any routing, but as you can see for two of the components (U4-U5-U3-U1-U2) I get some errors, what is the reason and how can I fix it?

The error is:



The error message is straight forward to read: "Collision between pad [on] U1 and region [on] keep-out layer". check your keep-out layer.

Did you create the footprint, or was it downloaded from somewhere?

@MrGerber I downloaded the footprint.

Looks like there is a keepout region in the footprint itself. I suggest bringing up the datasheet for the component and creating the footprint yourself. Footprints are always best to keep control of yourself.
